# How to create multiple threadpools i.e. multiple executors each with a single thread

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor, executor

I currently need to create multiple threadpools. Each threadpool is a single threaded threadpool. 
I assign tasks to each threadpool based upon a condition. So I need to maintain track of threadpools.

How can I do that?
Can I create an array of threadpools?

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

This is how we create 1 threadpool. Now I want to create 5 threadpools.

```
ExecutorService[] executor;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
executor[i]= Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
}
```

Is this ok? Is this right syntax? If not, can you suggest a way to do it?

Comment: Sure, you can do that. But why on earth would you want to?

Comment: I need my events to be ordered by their respective company. So all the events related to one company are sent to one threadpool. This way they will be executed in the same order I received for a particular company.

Comment: You know that the order they're sent and the order they're received is not necessarily the same, right ?

Comment: Sent to where? Received from where? Can you please elaborate your question. If you mean the order sent to threadpool and the order we receive from threadpool are not same. I think you are wrong. When you assign tasks to a single threaded threadpool, they will be completed in the same order because it maintains a queue for all the pending work.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, I believe it is possible to use just one single thread Executor since according to the documentation:

> Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an
>   unbounded queue. (Note however that if this single thread terminates
>   due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will
>   take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.) **Tasks are
>   guaranteed to execute sequentially**, and no more than one task will be
>   active at any given time. Unlike the otherwise equivalent
>   newFixedThreadPool(1) the returned executor is guaranteed not to be
>   reconfigurable to use additional threads.

Therefore with multiple input from multiple companies, the queue of the Executor will look like:

> [Company1Task1, Company2Task1, Company1Task2, Company3Task1,
>   Company1Task3, ...]

And the Executor will process it sequentially.

Comment: I think the point is that they don't have to be sequential between separate companies.